# Cigarette Smoking or Smoking Cigarette

Tags: word-order, gerunds

From the following sentence,

> **Cigarette smoking** harms nearly every organ of the body, causes many
>   diseases, and reduces the health of smokers in general.

Can we replace the bolded phrases with **smoking cigarette**? In what circumstances should we use these two?

Comment: Compare results in Google Books for *Everyone knows [that **smoking cigarette** is unhealthy*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22that+smoking+cigarette+is+unhealthy%22) with [*..that smoking **cigarettes** is unhealthy*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22that+smoking+cigarettes+is+unhealthy%22). Also consider [*...that **cigarette smoking** is unhealthy*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22that+cigarette+smoking+is+unhealthy%22) and [*that **cigarettes** smoking is unhealthy*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22that+cigarettes+smoking+is+unhealthy%22).

Comment: I would say that the first emphasises the _potential_ harmfulness of cigarettes and the second emphasises the _actual_ harm of smoking them. The first could be aimed at retailers and purchasers, the second could be aimed at, say, children in school.

Comment: First, _cigarette smoking_ is a noun compound and not a gerund. Second, *_smoking cigarette_ is ungrammatical; it should be either _smoking cigarettes_ or _smoking a cigarette_ if you mean it to be a gerund referring to the activity, or _a smoking cigarette_ if you mean it to be a noun phrase referring to a cigarette from which smoke is coming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In "*cigarette smoking*", "cigarette" qualifies the verb (what are you smoking?) and thus is singular.
You would write "smoking *cigarettes*" if you wanted to invert the words, as you would describe an activity and it takes more than one cigarette to reduce a smoker's health.
But you could write "Smoking *a* cigarette no longer makes you look cool."